Reducing and Reconstruction CNN model parameters using a VAE
Suppose I have a simple CNN model with 2 Conv2D layers, I trained this model on my image dataset, I am going to feed the parameters of this CNN model into a VAE (as input of encoder) to first reduce their parameters into an embedding space (Z or latent space of VAE). Then, I want to reconstruct the CNN parameters (with their original dimensions) using the output of the decoder of VAE.
I do not know how I can implement this in PyTorch and feed the parameters of the trained CNN into the encoder's input of the VAE model and finally reconstruct the vector of parameters to the CNN model parameters.
Here is the CNN model:
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x)

and the following code is used for VAE:
class VAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, image_channels=1, h_dim=1024, z_dim=32):
        super(VAE, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(image_channels, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            Flatten()
        )
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(h_dim, z_dim)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(h_dim, z_dim)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(z_dim, h_dim)
        
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            UnFlatten(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(h_dim, 128, kernel_size=5, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, kernel_size=5, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=6, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, image_channels, kernel_size=6, stride=2),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )
        
    def reparameterize(self, mu, logvar):
        std = logvar.mul(0.5).exp_()
        # return torch.normal(mu, std)
        esp = torch.randn(*mu.size())
        z = mu + std * esp
        return z
    
    def bottleneck(self, h):
        mu, logvar = self.fc1(h), self.fc2(h)
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
        return z, mu, logvar

    def encode(self, x):
        h = self.encoder(x)
        z, mu, logvar = self.bottleneck(h)
        return z, mu, logvar

    def decode(self, z):
        z = self.fc3(z)
        z = self.decoder(z)
        return z

    def forward(self, x):
        z, mu, logvar = self.encode(x)
        z = self.decode(z)
        return z, mu, logvar


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What is the question here? Are you trying to use the CNN's parameters for the encoder of the VAE? Right now, the VAE's encoder is the sequential layer. And the dimensions used in the NET class and the encoder of the VAE are not the same so there is no straightforward way of using the CNN's parameters in the VAE directly.
